# How to pull Google Cloud Platform VM metrics using Java?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to write a Java program to pull the GCP VM metrics such as CPU utilization, memory utilization, disks i/o, network, disk utilization etc. I want to pull this information per instance (Similar to CloudWatch in AWS).
I have set up the Stackdriver agent on each of my VM. I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

The Stackdriver agent sends the metrics to Stackdriver Monitoring, so you should use Stackdriver Monitoring to access this data. There is a [Java client library](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries) for this.